# Fire event after 2 seconds using javascript/jQuery

Tags: jquery, timer, keyevent

I have similar requirement like [jquery-run-code-2-seconds-after-last-keypress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4364729/jquery-run-code-2-seconds-after-last-keypress).

Now, when I use `@brad` code, it works fine when i do :-

```
$('input.username').keypress(debounce(function (event) {
    console.log('Search keypress');
}, 250));
```

But not when :-

```
$('#search').keypress(function () {
    debounce(function (event) {
        console.log('Search keypress');
   }, 2000);
});
```

[**Fiddle here**](http://jsfiddle.net/xQQ6h/7/). Any help would be really appretiated.

Edit:-

Initially I was doing something like below, which is not what I want-

```
$('#search').keypress(function () {
    setTimeout(function () {
      console.log('Search keypress');
    }, 3000);
});
```

Edit 2:- I want something very similar to below:- ***(Copied text from there )***

At the moment after 3 characters are entered it will search on every key press.

What I want is

> **Case1:** 
>   User enters tes
>   2 seconds pass
>   search performed
>
> ---
>
> **Case2:** 
>   User enters tes
>   1 second pass
>   user presses t
>   2 seconds pass
>   search is performed on test
>
> ---
>
> **Case3:** 
>   User enters tes
>   1 second passes
>   user presses t
>   1.5 seconds pass
>   user presses i
>   1.5 seconds pass
>   user presses n
>   1.5 seconds pass
>   user presses g
>   2 seconds pass
>   search in performed on testing

so as you can see,
the search action is only performed when there has been no key presses(or pastes ect) in the two seconds following a key press.

my basic idea is to.

on keydown
Call a function that sets a timeout,
the function  also sets a variable containing the last entry in the textbox.
when the timeout expires it checks the value in the box to see if it matches the value in the variable.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To debounce it using timeout:

{ BTW, use keyup event instead of keypress, delete key doesn't fire keypress event, see: http://www.quirksmode.org/js/keys.html }

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/xQQ6h/9/)

```
var timer;
$('#search').keyup(function () {
    clearTimeout(timer);
    timer = setTimeout(function (event) {

        console.log('Search keypress');
        var text = $('#search').val();

        $('#textTobeSearched').text(text);
    }, 2000);
});
```

Comment: Landed up in your solution... because its much easier for me to implement in Backbone Project. Thanks

Answer (score 7):

**UPDATE**: Here is with debounce at 2 seconds (wait 2 seconds): [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xQQ6h/15/)

```
$('#search').keyup( debounce(function() {
       console.log('Search keypress');
        var text = $('#search').val();

        $('#textTobeSearched').text(text); 
    }, 2000));
```

---

use [setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.setTimeout)

```
$('#search').keypress(function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        console.log('search keypress');
    }, 2000);
});
```

Comment: I may be not good in explaining the question but, in 2 seconds if i press 5 keys then it will fire 5 times. If i am not wrong.

Comment: well on each keypress a new keyup handler is bound, definitely not the way to go. You should just not nesting keyup binding event inside keypress, why doing that?

Answer (score 2):

`debounce` returns a function to be called. When used directly in the `keypress()` function, that returned function is your event handler. However, in your second code, you debounce the function but never actually call it.

```
debounce(function(event) {console.log("Search keypress");},2000)();
```